# Forcing the copy constructor

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I have a function like this:

```
Object Class::function() {
    Object o;
    return o;
}
```

Now when I call it like this:

```
Object o = Class::function();
```

it wants to use the move constructor. However I want it to use the copy constructor. How do I force it to not use the move constructor? I deleted the move constructor but then it won't compile.

EDIT: My constructors look like this:

```
Object(const Object & other) { ... }
Object(Object & other) { ... }
Object(Object && other)=delete;
```

Comment: On top of the stack, you will meet with copy elision, and the line "T v = func();" will construct directly in v, no copy nor move will occurs.

Comment: @galop1n: They why do I get the error: call to deleted constructor of 'Object', note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here Object(Object && other)=delete;

Comment: Because copy elision is an optimisation, the code should be correct even without it and by deleting the move ctor, you masked the default copy ctor. You need to bring it back. You should look for the rules of five.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a user-declared (manually declared) copy ctor, the move ctor will not be declared implicitly. Just leave out the move ctor, and it won't take part in overload resolution (i.e. don't define it as deleted, just leave out the entire declaration).

After [CWG DR 1402](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1402), the explanation is slightly different: a move ctor will always be declared even if there's a user-declared copy ctor, but it will be implicitly defined as deleted. And there's a special case for this deletion that makes the move ctor not take part in overload resolution. Note: If you explicitly delete the move ctor, that still means "if this function is selected by overload resolution, the program is ill-formed". The special case applies when the move ctor is defaulted (explicitly or implicitly), and when this leads to the move ctor being defined as deleted (as the implicit definition supplied for a defaulted function).

```
#include <iostream>

struct loud
{
    loud() { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; }
    loud(loud const&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    loud(loud&&) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
    ~loud() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

struct foo
{
    loud l;
    foo() = default;
    foo(foo const& p) : l(p.l) { /*..*/ }; // or `= default;`
    // don't add a move ctor, not even deleted!
};

foo make_foo()
{
    return {{}};
}

int main()
{
    auto x = make_foo();
}
```

Watch out for copy elision (e.g. use `-fno-elide-constructors`). Output:

```
default ctor
copy ctor
dtor
dtor
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e881ce35eed286b)

Comment: As an XY-problem, you could define the move ctor to perform a copy.

Comment: @gartenriese No problem. My answer still applies. I've made an edit some minutes ago to add a comment to point this out: The copy ctor only has to be declared manually to prevent the implicit declaration of a move ctor.

Comment: Ok, if I don't delete the move constructor, it works. That's weird, why is it not possible with a deleted move constructor?

Comment: @gartenriese Because `= delete;` is just another misnomer ;) It means "the program is ill-formed (=> compilation error) if this function is selected by overload resolution"

Comment: @gartenriese To add to the confusion, there's a special case now after DR1402 / in C++1y for the *implicit* deletion (defined as defaulted leading to defined as deleted) of the move ctor :(

Comment: @dyp clearly we need `= delete but not really just go away but don't make my program ill formed thanks`.

Comment: @Yakk I agree :) Maybe something like `= hide`? I think in this context, we might be able to use special identifiers similar to `override` and `final` w/o introducing a new keyword.

Comment: @dyp `= hide`?!? what, you don't like my choice of conditional keywords?  `=hide` is so ... ambiguous.  It could mean anything.

Comment: @Yakk hmmm what about `delete[]` for **really** delete the function?

Comment: @Yakk Or even better: `= void;` Sends the function declaration into nonexistance.

Comment: @Yakk oooooh now I see. you meant the whole sentence as a key-phrase.